# What is the difference between CSS margin and outline?

Tags: css

Both [margins](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_margin.asp) and [outline](http://w3schools.com/css/css_outline.asp) are used to add space around the border.

Comment: Where did you get the impression that outline is used to add space? Even the W3Schools link you have doesn't say that.

Comment: CSS specifications define what margin and outline are. They are separate concepts, and it is meaningless to ask what the difference is. Besides, the body of the question is based on a false premise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

outline only makes a line around any element to make it look different from the other elements.it will not give any space.whereas margin will give space around any element.

[image: outline example]

[image: margin example]

as in the above example u can see how left margin works.

Answer (score 7):

`outline` is just drawing an line around the border, without actually claiming space.

Here is a JSFiddle demonstrating both: http://jsfiddle.net/g8FXT/

Answer (score 4):

`outline` is purely decorative, it doesn't add any space around anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you give margin, it will give a space in the direction provided outside the container. Padding provides space inside the container. Outline is purely decorative.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm... I think margin and outline properties are pretty close. You can set the space around the element with both. There is a property, outline offset, within witch you can set the size (thickness) of outline property by units, same as margin. In my opinion, the difference between choosing one of them would be in the necessity of using an outline border or not. If you don't need it, it's ok to use margin to set the space around the element. If you need to set an outline border around the margin, it would be more logical to use outline property straightly, instead of setting the current element inside another father element with a set border already.